# Need to trigger a script if Memory reaches 80 %

Tags: bash, shell, out-of-memory, heap-dump

I have a bash script that takes HeapDump. But I need to trigger this automatically when the memory of my machine reaches 80 %.

Can anyone help me with the script? I have my environment running on AWS.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold=40
threshold2=45
freemem=$(($(free -m |awk 'NR==2 {print $3}') * 100))
usage=$(($freemem / 512))
if [ "$usage" -gt "$threshold" ]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

threshold=40
threshold2=45

freemem=$(($(free -m |awk 'NR==2 {print $3}') * 100))

usage=$(($freemem / 512))

if [ "$usage" -gt "$threshold" ]    @0.sh

Comment: Please [edit] your question to update it with this information. As you can see, code in comments basically just doesn't work, and your question should be self-contained anyway.

Comment: That's not a particularly elegant and usable cript, but it's not clear what's specificaly not working, except that the final `if` seems to end in the middle?

Comment: I am not able to add the entire script.

Comment: you can't add the script code to the comment , you must edit your question as @tripleee already pointed out.

Comment: I have added an image can guys see it?

Comment: Code as images is **not** acceptable. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the shell works is it examines the exit code of each program to decide what to do next. So you want to refactor your code so it returns 0 (success) when memory is below 80% and some other number otherwise.

Doing arithmetic in the shell is brittle at best, and impossible if you want floating point rather than integers. You are already using Awk - refactor all the logic into Awk for simplicity and efficiency.

```
#!/bin/bash
# declare a function
freebelowthres () {
    free -m |
    awk -v thres="$1" 'NR==2 {
        if ($3 * 100 / 512 > thres) exit(1)
        exit(0) }'
}
```

Usage: `if freebelowthres 80; then`...